# When to remove an IDE tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Is it correct etiquette to remove tags in the case where a user includes their IDE as a tag?

As an example, I quite often see the inclusion of the [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) tag. Regardless of whether the issue pertains to Android Studio.

[Example one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925338/android-studio-gridview-in-a-fragment-crashed). [Example two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923979/google-map-google-place-type).

1. Should the tag be removed in this case?
2. In the case of an otherwise perfectly formed question - should an edit be used *just* to remove the tag?

Comment: Yes and yes.  This happens in the .NET area sometimes with [tag:visual-studio] and that tag is usually entirely irrelevant to a problem with code.  If the post is already good quality, then tag-only edits are fine.

Comment: FWIW, when you get to 10k, you [get a handy shortcut](http://imgur.com/qqy1L5D) for editing _just_ the tags, so the system does encourage such tag-only edits.

Comment: If the tag has nothing to do with the question, remove it.  But you might want to skip just tag edits until you get to 10k, as once you hit the full editor you really should be editing more than just tags, if at all required.

Comment: I think this is a common problem with most IDE-related tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/xcode-is-just-an-ide

Comment: Happens in the Java arena a lot too. People flag the IDE they use to write code, but the question is absolutely unrelated to it. It becomes even worse when they start talking about "I developed this program in <IDE NAME>" rather than "in Java" - you just know that if any research was done at all, they were searching how to make the IDE do things and stuff for them :/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If the issue is not related whatsoever to the IDE and is only about the framework or language, and knowing the specific IDE the OP is using will not help answer the question or understand the issue, then removing the IDE tag is completely appropriate.

As for editing, yes, if you find that the question is completely perfect and only needs the retag, then editing is entirely appropriate. The concept of a "minor" edit is not always about number of characters that are changed, but by the importance of the change. And correct tagging can be very important to getting a question viewed by the appropriate experts and hence getting an answer.

However, in most cases, you will usually find something else that needs editing in the question. You should take the time to try to clean it up to the **best of your abilities**, so fixing the title to be meaningful, correcting any grammar or spelling mistakes can also help turn a meh question into a good question.  But if you aren't comfortable with your command of the English language and the grammar, don't feel obligated to try to fix something if you aren't sure how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. It is good to have that validated.

Comment: Excellent answer. The observation that "minor" !== "small diff" is crucial (and is one reason the minimum edit filter _really_ bugs me when I'm on sites that I don't frequent).

Comment: I think it’s also worth stating that there’s a huge difference between “minor” edits pre-2k and post-2k. When tiny edits just end up bumping something into the review queue, it’s a waste of people’s time, and it feels disingenuous because it gives rep. In contrast, small edits that don’t give rep and don’t consume reviewers’ time can really only be helpful (bumping aside, which seems unlikely), so even minor grammar fixes are game if they improve the post. Tagging, even more so.