# Should I remove an IDE tag when the question asks about feature comparisons?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

After reading [When to remove an IDE tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315195/etiquette-for-removing-ide-tags), I got to thinking about how users use IDE tags. One common question that I see is along the lines of:

> I used to use $old-editor, but have moved to $new-editor. In $old-editor, I was able to do $feature. Does $new-editor have an equivalent?

For concrete example, there is a question involving someone who has [Moved from Sublime Text to PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304855/sublime-ctrld-equivalents-in-phpstorm) and have tagged the question with both editors. However, my thought is that this question doesn't actually have anything to do with Sublime Text (i.e. $old-editor). It is really asking about features of PhpStorm ($new-editor) and should not have the [sublimetext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) tag because

- It's really about learning the features of the new editor. If the OP had never used the old editor in the first place, they wouldn't have tagged it in the first place.
- As I understand it, the point of tags is to allow experts to find questions they would be able/willing to answer. In this case, the answer doesn't involve the old editor, which makes this question noise to those searching by the old editor's tag.

In these cases, should I remove the tags for the old editor?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-languange-to-this-language-too-broad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you should remove the irrelevant tag to the old IDE.  As you point out, the question is entirely about the new IDE, so users only familiar with the old IDE would be powerless to help.  Tagging with the old IDE is completely unnecessary. For the specific question you linked to, I agree with [Braiam's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23304855/3) which made the question much more focused.  Notice that in addition to removing irrelevant tags, the edit made question more focused on the feature and also improved the title.

It might be easier to merely point to a feature that exists somewhere else, but that's being lazy and not defining the question fully.  A question about a feature that exists in a different IDE should explain what that feature actually is/does.  It can optionally provide the specific example from the old IDE, but the question should be understandable without relying on users being familiar with the other feature.

As always, please be thorough with the edits and fix as much as you can while retagging.

Comment: Ooh, diametrically opposed viewpoints.  How exciting!

Comment: @Makoto indeed.  I was trying to find a past discussion kinda related to tagging code conversions, but those discussions basically ended with "Don't bother with the tags since you should close the question instead."

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines.  This is one of those cases in which the question *should* remain open and more thought to it should be given.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's why I picked that question. I figured with 16 upvotes, the conversation wouldn't devolve into "that's a terrible question anyway."

Comment: @Makoto yep.  The why I don't like the idea of keeping the old IDE tags in.  It dissuades people from actually describing the problem.

Comment: I edited it further to name the action properly with my experience of Emacs.

Comment: @Braiam yeah that's a lot better.  Now that the command itself is fully explained.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would have left both tags intact.  The question is targeting those who have used or are familiar with Sublime Text *and* PHPStorm.

They may be looking for a specific feature in another IDE, but their experience only lends them to describe it in the older IDE.  That makes the goal and aim a bit clearer, and keeping the old tag aids in that.

Comment: You don't have to be familiar with $old-editor, to know if $new-editor has a specific $feature, as long as $feature is described well enough.